# Javascript "classes" prototype vs internal function declaration vs etc

Tags: javascript, oop

I know this has been answered before, but I am still confused (which is not entirely my fault as I notice the answers can be radically different from each other).

I come from a Java background so if you can define anything as static, private, public, etc like then that should help me understand.

Basically I want to make a completely custom class, but am unsure about prototype/etc.
Example (using one function type):

```
function myClass()
{
    var a;
    var b;

    var helper = function()
    {
        this.a += this.b;
    }

    var helper2 = function(a,b)
    {
        return(a + b);
    }

    var getA = function()
    {
        return(this.a);
    {

    var staticMethodThatNeedsToBePublic = function()
    {}
}

var myInstance = new myClass();

myClass.prototype.example1 = function(){};
myClass.example2 = function(){};
```

So how should this actually have been written? (I tried to include all the basic function types, but if I missed any feel free to add then) [note: I don't particularly care about this specific example, I just thought it might be helpful to the conversation but feel free to just answer my general question]

Comment: `var helper = function()` needs to be `this.helper = function()` if you want to access it like a Java class method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summery:

```
function MyClass(){
    //You can access everything from in here (and from all sub functions) including prototypes and statics that are defined afterwards.
    var privateVariable = "PriTest"; //Pair cannot by seen outside of MyClass
    function privateFunction(){
    }

    this.publicVariable = "pubTest"; //Pair can be seen by everything except static functions
    function publiFunction(){
    }this.publiFunction = publiFunction;

    this.prototypeFunction();      //This group could of been called like this from anywhere in this object
    alert(this.prototypeVariable);
    MyClass.staticFunction();
    alert(MyClass.staticVariable);
}

MyClass.prototype.prototypeFunction = function(){
    //Can access other prototypes, statics, and public functions and variables
    this.publicFunction();
    this.prototypeVariable;
    MyClass.staticFunction();
}
MyClass.prototype.prototypeVariable = "proTest"

MyClass.staticFunction = function(){
    //Can access other statics only
    alert(MyClass.staticVariable);
}
MyClass.staticVariable = "staTest"
```

Please tell me if I have anything wrong in the following.

Private (accessible internally): [Same as java]
`var variableName` || `function functionName` inside of the object.
Can only be accessed by other private or privileged functions.

Public and Privileged (accessible externally {can still work with all internal objects}): [Same as java's public]
`this.variableName` || `this.functionName = function(){ ... }` inside of the object.

Prototype (accessed by other prototypes): [almost outside of the class and can only access publicly available objects]
`Class.prototype.variableName` || `Class.prototype.functionName`
Functions declared this way will have access to any public or prototype variables. Attempts to change variable created this way will instead create a new public variable on the object and the prototype variable will be unavailable.

Static:  [Same as java?]
`Class.variableName` || `Class.functionName`
Can be changed by any function or method.

```
function MyClass(){
    //public, privileged, and private
    //Everything in here can see each other
    //Everything in here can see everything outside
}
//Prototype and Static
//Prototype, Basically a template that is used on an instance of a class (And therefore does not have access to any of the non public fields)
```

Prototype Example:

```
MyClass.prototype.proExample = function(){
    this.doSomething;
}
//Is basically equivalent to
function proExample(instanceOfMyClass){
    instanceOfMyClass.doSoemthing;
}
```

Will add to this after I do some tests.

Comment: Using just public and private fields so far and it is working great, it seems just like java in that regard (except this very similar syntax for very different results is confusing).

Comment: One thing to note is to not use this in the object unless you want to refer to a prototype of that object. `function MyClass(){var a = "test"; alert(this.a);/*Wrong (undefined): refer to it simply as a*/}`

Comment: And it is looking like after testing and having trouble that the public functions have to go first because they are undefined until after they code execution has passed then (unlike private functions). [Not that you cannot define a function privately and then simply go this.privateFunction = privateFunction; to make it public and globally accessible in the class]

Comment: And after more testing it appears that since functions are compiled first that no matter where you put the public functions they are not put into the `this.functionname` until after they are needed for any internal functions that call them.
So the best way to make a public function is to do `function publicFun(){...}this.publicFun = publicFun;`

Answer (score 13):

Short answer to your question: Use prototypes.  Always use prototypes.

The main difference is that if you attach a function using `this.foo = function(){}`, the function gets re-declared for every instance of the class.  Attaching using `func.prototype.foo = function(){}` means the function only ***ever*** gets declared once and the `this` property gets changed when calling it to the instance of the class it should be referring to.

Your code becomes:

```
function myClass(){
    // constructor
}

myClass.prototype   = new superClass();
myClass.constructor = myClass;
myClass.prototype = {
    helper  : function(){},
    helper2 : function(){}
};

var myInstance = new myClass();
```

---

Full list of how you can add methods & properties to a class from an article I wrote about 5 years ago:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3600451/Javascript-Basics-Part-8.htm

```
function Cat(name, color){
    /*
    Constructor: any code in here is run when the object is created
    */
    Cat.cats++;

    /*
    Private variables and functions - may only be accessed by private or privileged functions.

    Note that 'name' and 'color', passed into the Class, are already private variables.
    */
    var age  = 0;
    var legs = 4;
    function growOlder(){
        age++;
    }

    /*
    Public variables - may be accessed publicly or privately
    */
    this.weight = 1;
    this.length = 5;

    /*
    Privileged functions - may be accessed publicly or privately
    May access Private variables.

    Can NOT be changed, only replaced with public versions
    */
    this.age = function(){
        if(age==0) this.length+=20;

        growOlder();
        this.weight++;
    }
}

/*
Prototyped Functions - may be accessed publicly
*/
Cat.prototype = {
    talk:     function(){ alert('Meow!'); },
    callOver: function(){ alert(this.name+' ignores you'); },
    pet:      function(){ alert('Pet!'); }
}

/*
Prototyped Variables - may be accessed publicly.
May not be overridden, only replaced with a public version
*/
Cat.prototype.species = 'Cat';

/*
Static variables and functions - may be accessed publicly
*/
Cat.cats = 0;
```

Comment: I did some light editing to the order, since I believe it helps. Feel free to undo it if you think it's not right. :)

Comment: Will read the suggested reading, but will leave some questions now before I forget them: Should the internally global variables be prototyped as well?

My issue with this always use prototype is that that means that everything will by publicly accessible, right? and that is not OO at all in my opinion. Also is there no static way of defining variables that do not need to access any non static class objects?

In your example `Cat.Cats` confuses me.

`myClass.constructor = myClass;`???

Comment: Read it but all the code examples seem to be missing and overall that made it moderately confusing.

Comment: "Always use prototypes" is far too strong a statement. There are plenty of valid reasons to use closures. (Saying prototypes are more efficient is a micro optimisation)

Comment: There is one case where the attaching a function is useful. When a function is the target of an event handler the attached function will get called correctly with the correct 'this'.

Comment: @JohnMott - The `this` scope of a function has literally nothing to do with how it's added to an object.  The only thing that controls the `this` binding are a) what object it's called from, b) overrides like `.call()` and `.apply()`, and bonus c) arrow functions in ES6

Comment: @Mark I should have been more specific in saying that I found that an attached function worked when used as an event handler when a prototype didn't work and not discussed how 'this' is assigned, because I don't know the rules for how 'this' works.

Comment: @JohnMott - There's no correlation between how a function is attached to an object that could have any impact on using it as an event handler :)  There's something else going on with your code, like utilizing a closure or whatnot.  `this.method = function(){ ... }` will have access to local variables within the parent function, a prototype won't, but this isn't specific to event handlers or anything else, it's more of a code style thing.

Comment: I stand corrected, sir. I had a project that I was fighting with and having an attached function fixed it, but I just created a fiddle with an attached and a prototype and it worked so there was something about the organization that wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

This confuses a lot of people, because Javascript uses a very different notion of inheritance and class.  In Javascript, *everything*, including classes, is simply an object.  All the methods and such that make up the *class* part is contained in an object called `prototype`.  Part of that is a function called `init`.  When you do `new Foo()` you are constructing a new object, and some `init` method copies the appropriate contents, including the prototype, to that new object.

So when you add a function to `prototype` through

```
 myClass.prototype.example1 = function(){};
```

you're actually adding a new method to the *class*, which would then be inherited in any instance of myClass you construct.  In the second case,

```
 myClass.example2 = function(){};
```

you simply add the new method to the original myClass object.  In Java terms, that's basically changing that to be a new type object, one that acts just like a myClass *except* it now has an `example2()` method.

**Update**

Another answer metions Crockford's Classical Inheritance note.  I'd recommend reading the [Prototypal Inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) paper as well.

**Another update**

Okay, let's back up a second.  First, what's an object?  Basically, it's a structure that combines *state* and *behavior*.

We have the idea of a Number that has an add method, and we have a kind of Number called an Integer that "behaves like" a Number but is limited to values in a particular range.  In a language like Java, you might have

```
abstract class Number {
    public void addTo(Number arg);
}
```

and then

```
class Integer extends Number {
    int val;
    public void addTo(Integer arg){ val += arg; }
}
```

(And don't hassle me about details of Java, I'm trying to make a point.)

What you've said here is that there are potentially many objects that are Numbers, and they all have a behavior called `addTo`.  Mathematically, a collection of things that are identified by a common property is sometimes called an "equivalence class", and that's how we get the name "class".

We've also identified a special kind of Number called an Integer, which has a bounded range of values, between -32767 and 32768.  (Quiz: why those values?)  Still, it acts in every way like a Number: you can `addTo` integers as well.  That statement "acts in every way like -- but with these restrictions" is commonly abbreviated to "is a" and is what we mean by "inheritance."

So now you write

```
Integer a, b;
// they get initial values somehow, left as an exercise
a.addTo(b);
```

and the compiler figures out to find the *object* `a`, finds its particular behavior `addTo` and knows how to hook everything up to make it work.  Sometimes -- like in early versions of C++ -- this had to be done at compile time; in later C++ and in Java, there's also a way to make the connection at run time ("late binding") which basically comes down to hving a table someplace that says

> If I have an integer and I need an addTo method, here's its address; use that.

Javascript, and some previous languages starting with Self, do this a little differently.  Now, an object is just a structure that contains ... stuff.  Some of this stuff may be data, and some may be functions.  The idea of a "class" can be completely abstracted away; the "class" is just the collection of all the objects that have the exact same contents.  So, in Javascript, we might make our "Integer" class like

```
 var Integer = {  // we're defining an object as a literal
     int val,
     addTo : function(b){ val += b ; }
 }
```

(Again, don't worry if this is really perfect javascript, the point is to explan the concept.)

If we copy this object named `Integer`, say to `Integer2`, then both contain a `val` and a function named `addTo`.  We can say they're both "of the same class" because they have exactly the same state and methods.

The question is, how can we implement this copying?  You can just run through the whole thing bit by bit, but that has some other problems, so we defined a special object in the contents of *every* javascript object named `prototype`, and we put all the methods and stuff -- everything we would want to copy to build another object in the same class -- in that.  Now we'd have something like

```
  var Integer = {
      prototype : {
        int val,
        addTo : function(b){ val += b; }
      }
  }
```

We add to the language an operator `new` that basically just copies the prototype object.  When we write

```
  var a = new Integer();
```

`a` is now an object that has the same prototype as all the other `Integer` objects. When we write

```
  a.addTo(b);
```

all the interpreter has to do is look in the `prototype` object contained in `a` and find its method named `addTo`.

Why do this?  Because now all the complexity of compiling in the classes, adding syntax, and figuring out when to bind at compile time or run time, plus managing the run time tables and so forth, turns into two simple operations:

- know how to make a *deep copy* of `prototype`
- how how to look up something by name in `prototype`.

That second approach is "prototype inheritance".

Comment: I cannot figure out the difference between "you're actually adding a new method to the class," and "you simply add the new method to the original myClass object"

Comment: Prototypal Inheritance paper: Just read it and I am not sure what he is talking about or how I would ever use those code snippets he supplied.
The main problem might be that I have no idea what JS being a Prototypal language means.

Comment: Try this wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming